# my ajax response only works in first table row

Tags: php, ajax

Im new to ajax and I really need help for this one. I really dont have any idea how to solve this, here is my problem: i want my ajax response to only show where I made changes on the select box inside my table. I already solved how to pop out another select box whenever I select in a first select box but the problem is it only happens in first table row of my table.
My ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function guest() {

        var rooms = document.getElementById("select_rooms").value;
        var some = document.getElementById("room_type").value;
        var url = "guest.php?rooms="+rooms+"&id="+some;
        var method = "GET";
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          } else { 
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
              document.getElementById("guest").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
          xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
          xmlhttp.send(null);
           document.getElementById("guest").innerHTML = "loading...";
        }


</script>
```

AND for my table:

```
                        <table>
                            <?php
                                    $query_roomtype = mysql_query("select * from tb_category");
                                    while($row_type = mysql_fetch_array($query_roomtype)){
                                        $query2 = mysql_query("select sum(no_of_room) As sum from tb_reserve where status != 'Checkout' AND arrival < '$end' AND departure > '$start' AND category_id = '$row_type[category_id]' OR status != 'Cancelled' AND arrival < '$end' AND departure > '$start' AND category_id = '$row_type[category_id]'");
                                            $sum_query2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
                                            $ar = $row_type['max_room'] - $sum_query2['sum'];
                                ?>
                            <tr>

                                <td style='width: 40%;'>

                                    <h4><?php echo $row_type['category_name']; ?></h4>
                                    <img src='<?php echo $row_type['photos']; ?>' width='250' style='border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid #999;'> <br /><br /> 

                                    <p style="text-align: left;">
                                    Occupancy: <u><?php echo $row_type['max_guest']; ?> Guest </u><br /> 
                                    Size: <u><?php echo $row_type['size']; ?> </u><br />
                                    Price: <u><?php echo number_format($row_type['price'], 2, '.', ','); ?></u> <br />
                                    </p>
                                </td>                                   
                                <td style="text-align: left;">
                                    <?php echo $row_type['description']; ?>
                                    <hr>
                                    Available Rooms: <?php echo $ar . " / " . $row_type['max_room']; ?><br />

                                    <div class="contact-wrap">
                                    <div class="main-reservation-form-caption">Select No. of Rooms: </div>
                                    <div class='select-styling-wrap1' style="border: 1px solid #999; width: 50px;"> 
                                    <select style="width: 50px; border: 1px solid #999; height: 40px;" id="select_rooms" name="select_rooms" onchange="guest()">    
                                        <option value="">0</option>                     
                                        <?php                                   
                                            $i = 1;
                                            while($i <= $ar){
                                                echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                                                $i++;
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                                    <div class="guest-wrap">
                                    <div id="guest" class="guest">

                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Do not use the `mysql_` functions

They are deprecated. Right now you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html). Please read up on either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). This is really, really important.

## Only make one query to the database

Right now you are making one query to the database per room type. That causes unnecacary load on the database and makes your code slow. Not as important as the above point, but still worth fixing. Use [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp):

```
SELECT
  SUM(tb_reserve.no_of_room) AS sum,
  [all the fields from tb_category you want]
FROM tb_reserve, tb_category
WHERE
  tb_category.category_id = tb_reserve.category_id AND
  [all your other conditions]
GROUP BY tb_category.category_id
```

## Your question

You only get changes to the first row of the table because all of your select boxes and guest divs have the same ID - `select_rooms` and `guest`. The `getElementById` simply returns the first element with that ID, which is the one in the first row.

The solution is to give them different ids, like `select_rooms_1`, `select_rooms_2` and son on, and similarly `guest_1`, `guest_2` and so on. Then you need to inform the `guest()` function about what row to change. This can be done in many ways.

One way is to simply change the onchange attribute on every row so instead of `onchange="guest()"` it says `onchange="guest(1)"`, `onchange="guest(2)"` and so on. Then, you change the `guest()` function to take that parameter:

```
function guest(room_number) {
  var rooms = document.getElementById("select_rooms_" + room_number).value;
  ...
```

Another way is to figure out what row you are on using a refernce to the element that triggered the event, either by looking at its id or a cutom `data-row-number` attribute:

```
<select id="select_rooms_1" data-row-number="1" ...>
```

To be able to get that information you need a reference to the element that fired the onchange event. If you [add the event using JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) instead of using the inline `onclick` attribute you will have access to the variable `this` inisde the `guest()` function, so you could do something like this:

```
var row_number = this.getAttribute("data-row-number");
var rooms = document.getElementById("select_rooms_" + row_number).value;
```

Also, it might be easier to write this code using a JavaScript library, like [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Comment: thanks a lot :D,.. ill try this later because im in school right now